# Hide method parameter name labels

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to hide method parameter name labels in C# code editor? It makes lines longer and more difficult to review.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.3

**EDIT**: It turned out that it's a Resharper feature.

Comment: Are you mean the [parameter hints from Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html) by chance or written in code?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9464162

Comment: @GürolMehmetÇetin that post is talking about code, here it is perfectly fine to support the point of the question.

Comment: Are you sure that's not hand-written code? The first two parameters have no names. If you don't want that code, delete it

Comment: But some countires block to access https://i.stack.imgur.com. So we don't understand the question.

Comment: Yo're right. Stackoverflow have to solve this problem :(

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt ah, you are right, it's a Resharper feature. Thank you for your help!